# No error message return to my mobile app(swift) from nodejs

Tags: node.js, swift, express

I'm working on a mobile application(ios app). I use nodejs and express on the backend. When I request from the mobile application, no error message is returned in the response. **Everything works fine when I use Postman.**

login function in swift

```
func login(email:String,password:String,completion: @escaping (Error?) -> ()){

        guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:3000/auth/login") else {return}

        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"

        let params = ["email":email, "password":password]


        do {
            let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .init())

            urlRequest.httpBody = data
            urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")

            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, res, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    completion(err)
                    print(err)
                    return
                }
                guard let data = data else{return}
                completion(nil)
            }.resume()
        } catch {
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
```

auth.js

```
router.post('/login', async (req,res) =>{

    //login validation
    const {error} = loginValidation(req.body);
    if (error) return res.send({message:error.details[0].message});

    //checking if the email exist
    const user = await User.findOne({
        email:req.body.email
    });

    if(!user) return res.status(400).json('invalid Email');
    //checking pash is correct
    const validPass = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password,user.password)
    if(!validPass) return res.status(400).json('password is not match');

    sess = req.session;
    sess.email = req.body.email;

    console.log(sess);
    //create and assing a token
    const token = jwt.sign({_id:user._id},process.env.SECRET_TOKEN);
    res.header('auth-token',token).json(token);


});
```

Note: index.js

```
const authRoute = require('./routes/auth');

app.use('/auth', authRoute);
```

Comment: I mean it won't return an error if it's working fine. So what's the problem here?

Comment: For example, I have a login page and I can login to the application even though I entered wrong information in the username and password in the login page. No error response occurring in the backend is coming to my mobile application.

Comment: But does the error itself appear at the back end? Because here we are trying to see if it's just that the error has not been sent to the front end or there is no error at all.

Comment: yes, I can see the error in the backend. For example, when I print the error message as consolo.log as a result of validation, I get the error message. But it does not go to mobile application this error message.

Comment: it also works flawlessly when I use the postman app.

Comment: Can you show us what the error message says?

Comment: I entered the wrong email address in the body of my post request and sent a request. response "invalid Email"

Comment: So that must be the problem right?

Comment: Yes, I do not receive the error message when I do the same with the mobile application. Since there is no error message, whatever I write instead of email and pass, I can always log into the system. if i couldn't explain the situation enough if u want I can share project's github link

Comment: Yes. Please. That will definetly help.

Comment: you can reach via this link : https://github.com/MCTOK1903/RestfullAPIWithNodeJS

Comment: Ok. I see. Do you think passport.js is perhaps useful for your project?

Comment: I've never used it before. I recently started writing and learning backend stuff.

Comment: I think you can give passport a try.

Comment: I'll consider u advice . Thank you